# iOS app will not launch until restart phone

Tags: ios, swift, realm, crashlytics

I'm not entirely sure where to start with this. I have an iOS app in Swift for iOS 10.3 that uses Crashlytics and Realm, and several times a day, when I launch my app, it just sits at the launch screen, and then promptly closes. I get no logs when this happens (through crashlytics, or on the device), and the only way this solves itself is if I restart my phone, reinstall the app, or if I try again several hours later. I don't know how to debug this issue.

My application launching function is as follows:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.createDirectories()
    var performShortcutDelegate = true
    let dir: URL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.BackloggerSharing")!
    let realmPath = dir.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")

    let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: realmPath, schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: {
        migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            // auto migrate
        }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    self.compactRealm(at: realmPath)

    (UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])).tintColor = Util.appColor
    UISlider.appearance().tintColor = Util.appColor
    self.window?.tintColor = Util.appColor

    if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
        self.shortcutItem = shortcutItem
        performShortcutDelegate = false
    }

    return performShortcutDelegate
}

func createDirectories() {
    let playlistsFolder = Util.getPlaylistImagesDirectory()

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: playlistsFolder.absoluteString) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: playlistsFolder, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func compactRealm(at realmPath: URL) {
    let defaultParentURL = realmPath.deletingLastPathComponent()
    let compactedURL = defaultParentURL.appendingPathComponent("default-compact.realm")
    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try? Realm()
        try! realm?.writeCopy(toFile: compactedURL)
    }
    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: realmPath)
    try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: compactedURL, to: realmPath)
}
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to put breakpoint in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:? Does it enter this method?

Comment: If I relaunch the app from xcode, it works fine. It's just if I have been using my app for a while, whether from xcode or from testflight, this will happen. I haven't been able to catch this happening with a debugger attached.

Comment: Do you have +initialize method redefined in AppDelegate?

Comment: Also it is possible that if you return FALSE from that method the app will not start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was that I had a realm opening in my Today Extension that was not closing the realm instance. When I would load my application, I would attempt to open another realm (now in a second process which is unsupported), and perform migration and compaction. I have updated the Today Extension to close realm instances while they are not needed.

This debugging was determined from my app not saving logs because I reached the max allowed for an application (25). I cleared the logs, found them, symbolicated them, and found that Realm struggled upon opening.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Realm, and you make changes in Database you should reinstall the app otherwise it crashes on Launch screen,
if above is not an issue then maybe your app uses maximum memory, or some of your code causes memory leakages.

Comment: I don't make changes to anything. The app will work just fine, and then one time it will just stop working. Relaunching from xcode works just fine, but if I am just tapping on the app from the springboard, it will just hang and crash sometimes, and I won't be able to open it, no matter how many times I try. I would imagine killing an app would free its memory too, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: when you tapping on app from springboard, is your app is in background state or not exist in background

Comment: maybe returning false in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ` cause the issue.